# Laravel strange time error "now - 6.0E+26 seconds"

Tags: laravel

I see this error constantly in Laravel application.

I use ***Carbon::now()*** only and I'm not sure what's happening. I tried google search and didn't get even one result about this.

> [2019-10-30 09:55:03] production.ERROR: "now - 6.0E+26 seconds" is not a valid date. {"userId":1659,"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): \"now - 6.0E+26 seconds\" is no$
>       [stacktrace]

Carbon usage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3qPg.png

Comment: Show us some code where you are using Carbon.

Comment: What are you trying to do? you cant do it like this...

Comment: Fill selectpicker with years from 1900 > 2019 (current year). This works, after refresh I don't see the error, sometimes happen

Comment: @Zeljko I have the same issue, and after refresh, error disappear. if you have any solution please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this.
From your controller:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$year = $now->year;

return view('myView', compact('year'));
```

and in your view:

```
@for($i = 1900; $i <= $year; $i++)
<option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
@endfor
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't change anything, even if I knew already to use carbon within the controller, that's not the problem.

Comment: Have you tried it? show us the error you got after trying this, please. @Zeljko

Comment: I tried but the error is the same as I posted in the question

Answer (score 0):

I might have a better solution for you. As of `Carbon 1.29`, you can set date interval from one date to another. There's a new [CarbonPeriod](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period) class that does exactly what you want. So in this case, you want to display all the dates from 1900. till today. Inside your controller, do this:

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromDate(1900, 1, 1);
$endDate = Carbon::now();

$dates = new DatePeriod($startDate, new DateInterval('P1D'), $endDate);

return view('your_view', $dates);
```

Now you will get all the dates from the given period. Keep in mind that `DatePeriod` is an interator, so if you want an actual array, do this;

```
$dates->toArray();
```

Now, inside your view, iterate through all the years, and put them in the select option:

```
@foreach($dates as $date)
  <option value="{{$date->year}}">{{$date->year}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Tinker output: 
[image]

If you have any issues with this, let me know.